# jQuery/Javascript find and replace all instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace all instances of a pattern with regular expressions in Javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041276/replace-all-instances-of-a-pattern-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript-jque)
>   [How can I use jQuery to style /parts/ of all instances of a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word)

Say I have the code:

```
<div class="replace">
     <i>Blah</i>
     <u>Blah</u>
</div>
```

Now, I want to replace all the `<` within the div with something else.

If I use `$('#div').html().replace('<','somethingElse');` it only replaces the first instance.

How can I replace all the instances?

Thanks

Comment: you need to use a little regex, Kevin B is refering to it I think correctly, /g is ur regex command to repeat after first find

Answer (score 9):

Use regex

```
"anyString".replace(/</g,'somethingElse');
```

If you want to replace it inside the div then try this.

```
$('#div').html($('#div').html().replace(/</g,'somethingElse'));
```

Comment: How I do if I want to do this for whole html? $('#html').html($('#html').replace(/name/g, 'somethingElse')); does'nt work.

Comment: @Phiber Did you ever learn how? If so, let me know, please.