# jquery replacing special characters in a string

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I will replace `c:\pictures\picture1.png` to `c:\\pictures\\picture1.png`

i.e:

```
var data="c:\pictures\picture1.png"
data=data.raplace('\','\\');
```

in asp.net it can run with

```
data=data.replace('\\','\\\\');
```

when I use this method in jquery it replaced only the firs '\' character and it comes so:

```
c:\\pictures\picture1.png
```

how can I replace all '\' characters

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708653/jquery-javascript-find-and-replace-all-instances

Comment: thank it runs with data.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can perform a global replacement by using g..

The g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

```
.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\'));

data = data.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you search for the \ using a regular expression, you can use the g flag at the end of the expression to indicate you want to do a "global" search.

Also, your example is off.  Any time you want to use the literal `\` you need to write it twice as in `\\`.

```
var data="c:\\pictures\\picture1.png"
data = data.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\')
```

Answer (score 1):

Expressions will help you here: http://jsfiddle.net/jC8hM/

```
var data = "c:\\pictures\\picture1.png"

alert(data);
data = data.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");

alert(data);
```

To write a single instance of "\" you need to write "\". So to write "\", you need "\\".