# If numbers and special characters are in input

Tags: jquery, regex, input

I have an input field for phone number and I need it to do something only if the input value contains numbers AND/OR special characters...

I have the following:

```
var inputphone = $('input#phone').val()

if($.isNumeric(inputphone) || inputphone.match(/.^\+$/)){
    //action
}
```

But this works only with numbers, if i write the phone number like 0000.000.000 it won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @blgt Using regex could work for me but I need it to work internationally too. I only needed a way to permit some characters I define, I don't want to limit the digit number and stuff like that since in my country phone numbers vary from 4 digits to 12 and in various formats.

Comment: Both of these concerns have been discussed extensively in the 32 answers to the linked question. This isn't a new problem, so you shouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. If there are *significant* differences that are *not* discussed there, please edit them into the question above

Comment: Found what I needed ^^ Thanks :) It goes like : /^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$/i

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the characters used to separe groups of numbers. As explained in this thread [jQuery/Javascript find and replace all instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708653/jquery-javascript-find-and-replace-all-instances), you can use a regex:

```
var inputphone = $('input#phone').val()
inputphone.replace(/[\.\-\ ]/g, '');

if($.isNumeric(inputphone) || inputphone.match(/.^\+$/)){
    //action
}
```

In this case, `.`, `-` and `[Space]` are removed from the `inputphone` string.

Comment: can you to explain what does `/.^\+$/` regular?

Comment: well, that is ok but I needed dots and - and a lot more, I actually found this : /^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$/i and it's great